# Is it possible to use kafka to respond to aggregate?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm following the spring kafka aggregate example here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-aggregate

I've built a few variants of that example to build out more complicated data structures, rather than just a string append, and that all works well.

However, I'm interested in using a listener, whether that be a cloud-stream, kafa-stream, or native Kafka to respond to new aggregate values. I'm having trouble finding any specific examples of this, or even anything kinda close, so I'm hoping to get a nudge in the right direction.

I can always manually write the aggregate to another stream from the aggregate method

```
kStream.groupBy(...).aggregate(
    ...
    (s, domainEvent, agg) -> {
        ...
        // Update aggregate
        ...
        secondaryStreamChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(agg).build());
    },
    ...
);
```

But this doesn't seem ideal, since it would render the actual aggregate/snapshot stream kind of superfluous. It also now kinda breaks the isolation of the aggregate method and ties it into another stream.

I could notify some other handler with the key being aggregated, but there's a race condition potential there between execution of the downstream handler and completion of the aggregate.

Essentially I would like to have an event stream, that then is aggregated, and then have a method that is invoked and provided at least the aggregate key, or key/aggregate pair. Ideally, the method would not be invoked until the aggregate change is available. Is this possible using the existing cloud-stream, kafka-stream, or Kafka APIs? Is there another way (ie... am I trying to tie this use-case too closely to Kafka/streams, where it perhaps doesn't need to be) ?

Comment: You wouldn't write to another topic like that. You'd use `.to()` method as an output of one stream to a topic. But yes, they're coupled and that's the encouraged pattern... You'd have a second application listening to the output topic of the aggregate

Comment: What about `kStream.groupBy(...).aggregate(...).toStream().foreach()` ? You might want to disable record caching to ensure that `foreach()` is called for every update (cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html)